# Java: get username from uid

Tags: java, operating-system

I'm reading a `tar` archive which has numeric owner and group ids.

I want to set the file ownership to those given in the archive.  *Assuming* of course that the name to id mapping is the same on the target machine as on the source of the archive, how can I do this?

- The only way to do this in Java is `Files.setOwner()`.
- `Files.setOwner()` requires a `UserPrincipal` argument.
- The `UserPrincipal` interface has a `getName()` method.
- The `tar` archive contains only numerical ids.
- If I have a name, I can create a `UserPrincipal` object.

but there seems to be no 'clean' method of obtaining the name of the user associated with a particular numerical uid, if one exist.  By 'clean' I mean a JVM method and not reading and parsing */etc/passwd*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't provide any direct APIs for retrieving the OS level user name from a numeric UID. The UserPrincipal object, as you correctly pointed out, works with a user's name, not a user's numeric identifier.

The most thorough solution would be to incorporate a JNI (Java Native Interface) or JNA (Java Native Access) solution. JNI and JNA can call C/C++ functions. You could use JNI or JNA to call the system function `getpwuid` to retrieve user name from UID.

Comment: Thank you.  As I have to use JNI, I went with `jni.posix.POSIX.chown()` as the most direct and simple solution.